# Removing empty rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with empty values ​​in rows

[image]

How can I remove these empty values? I have already tried `data.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)` and `data.dropna()` but that didn't change anything.
What other ways are there to drop empty rows from a dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)?

Comment: I tried it right away, but there was no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
data = data.replace('', np.nan).dropna()
```

Update

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').dropna()
```

Comment: Tried it, no effect

Comment: @Sam324 is that empty or it is ' '?

Answer (score 1):

As you have spaces in a numeric variable, I'm assuming it got read in as a string. The way I would solve this in a robust way is following the following:

```
data = {'lattitude': ['', '38.895118', '', '', '', '45.5234515', '', '40.764462'],
        'longitude': ['', '-77.0363658', '', '', '', '-122.6762071', '', '-11.904565']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Change the fields to a numeric field. errors='coerce' will change the values it can not convert to a numeric to pd.NaN.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

[image]

The only thing you'll have to do now is drop the NA's

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

[image]

Another possible solution is to use regular expressions. In this case it's a negative match to any character. So if the field does not have a character, it'll be caught here. Of course there are multiple regex possible here.

```
mask = (df['lattitude'].str.contains(r'(^\S)') & df['longitude'].str.contains(r'(^\S)'))
df = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose latitude is between -90 and 90.

```
data = data[data['latitude'] <= 90]
```

this should work, no matter they are Nan or ''

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hacky, but works.

```
data.fillna("").replace('', pd.NA, inplace=True)
```